# ME APARECE EN BLANCO MI ARCHIVO .JS AL ABRIRLO DESDE NEOVIM

Tags: javascript, macos, vim, programacion-asincrona, nvim

estoy empezando a trabajar con NEOVIM y se me presento un problema. al abrir mi archivo desde la terminal poniendo "nvim index.js" me aparece en blanco el archivo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Simplemente abriste la terminal y tecleaste ese comando o primero cambiaste de directorio?

Comment: Simplemente abri la terminal y tecle el comando

Comment: ¿Cuál es la ubicación del archivo? Debes cambiarte a ese directorio o proporcionar toda la ruta al abrirlo con neovim.